# How to add column to duplicated query?

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a table called `logs` that contains these columns:

```
id - message - source - created_at - version - ...(another columns here)
```

I want to count the `message` that has been duplicated in `logs` and get three columns of the query which are

`source - created_at - version`

Note:

- `source` has a fixed value
- `created_at` is not a fixed value (I want to get the latest date from the last record)
- `version` is not a fixed value (I want to get the last version from the last record)

my wrong query:

```
SELECT
    MESSAGE,
    SOURCE,
--  VERSION,
    COUNT(id)
FROM
    logs
WHERE
    LEVEL = 'debug'
GROUP BY
    MESSAGE,
    SOURCE
--  VERSION
HAVING
    COUNT(id) > 1
ORDER BY
    COUNT(id)
    DESC;
```

The result is I get the wrong number of counting cuz of the value of `version` is not the same in all rows!

So how can get the number of duplicate messages with `source - created_at - version` could

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you want the last version, create an array of versions and order them by the timestamp. When done, pick the first one:

```
SELECT
    MESSAGE,
    SOURCE,
    MAX(created_at),
    (ARRAY_AGG(VERSION ORDER BY created_at DESC))[1] AS last_version, -- use an ORDER BY
    COUNT(id)
FROM
    logs
WHERE
    LEVEL = 'debug'
GROUP BY
    MESSAGE,
    SOURCE
HAVING
    COUNT(id) > 1
ORDER BY
    COUNT(id) DESC;
```

Comment: THANKS, it works!! I just add `(ARRAY_AGG(created_at ORDER BY created_at DESC))[1] AS created_at,` for created_at ,is it OK ? or there is another way to get the last created_at

Comment: If you want the MAX(version) you could use that. I thought you wanted the last version based on the timestamp.

Comment: Yeah the version is correct but I need to add created_at also to the columns  with query

Comment: Use MAX(), see the updated statement

Comment: With max the query return empty, but `ARRAY_AGG(created_at ORDER BY created_at DESC))[1] AS created_at,` I got created_at!

Comment: MAX() should not return a NULL when there is some value for the group. But without data, I can't see what is going wrong.

Comment: Sorry human error :) thanks everything is working